# How to create apache spark standalone cluster for integration testing using TestContainers?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, apache-spark, integration-testing, testcontainers

Is anyone knows how to create an apache-spark cluster for integration testing using testContainers https://www.testcontainers.org/

any running example please, i am struggling to find that.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to create this kind of integration test using the *GenericContainer* class and the *bitnami/spark* image. It's the following code (I wrote it for a [library](https://github.com/fabiogouw/spark-aws-messaging) that writes a dataframe to AWS SQS).

The idea is creating a Spark container (in this case, it's not a cluster, but just the master node), copying all the files needed to run the test (some Python files and all the dependencies), issuing the *spark-submit* command and checking the final state (a message in the Localstack's SQS service in another container).

```java
    @Testcontainers
    public class SparkIntegrationTest {
    
        private static Network network = Network.newNetwork();
    
        @Container
        public LocalStackContainer localstack = new LocalStackContainer(DockerImageName.parse("localstack/localstack:0.12.13"))
                .withNetwork(network)
                .withNetworkAliases("localstack")
                .withServices(SQS);
    
        @Container
        public GenericContainer spark = new GenericContainer(DockerImageName.parse("bitnami/spark:3.1.2"))
                .withCopyFileToContainer(MountableFile.forHostPath("build/resources/test/.", 0744), "/home/")
                .withCopyFileToContainer(MountableFile.forHostPath("build/libs/.", 0555), "/home/")
                .withNetwork(network)
                .withEnv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", "test")
                .withEnv("AWS_SECRET_KEY", "test")
                .withEnv("SPARK_MODE", "master");
    
        @Test
        public void shouldPutASQSMessageInLocalstackUsingSpark() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String expectedBody = "my message body";    // the same value in resources/sample.txt
    
            AmazonSQS sqs = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withEndpointConfiguration(localstack.getEndpointConfiguration(SQS))
                    .withCredentials(localstack.getDefaultCredentialsProvider())
                    .build();
            sqs.createQueue("my-test");
    
            org.testcontainers.containers.Container.ExecResult lsResult =
                    spark.execInContainer("spark-submit",
                            "--jars", "/home/spark-aws-messaging-0.3.1.jar,/home/deps/aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.12.jar,/home/deps/aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.12.12.jar",
                            "--master", "local",
                            "/home/sqs_write.py",
                            "/home/sample.txt",
                            "http://localstack:4566");
    
            System.out.println(lsResult.getStdout());
            System.out.println(lsResult.getStderr());
    
            assertEquals(0, lsResult.getExitCode());
    
            String queueUrl = sqs.getQueueUrl("my-test").getQueueUrl()
                    .replace("localstack", localstack.getContainerIpAddress());
            List<Message> messages = sqs.receiveMessage(queueUrl)
                    .getMessages();
            assertEquals(expectedBody, messages.get(0).getBody());
        }
    }
```

There's still a drawback: It's a black box, I can't measure code coverage.